# Class variables kept private through a library

Tags: java, android, variables, encapsulation

Oddly enough until now, there really hasn't been a need to be sure that a private variable remained private.  But, there is sensitive data that is to be passed into the library, and passed back as well.  Perhaps restructuring is the appropriate route so that we are not passing back the same data type that is being passed in, it just makes sense to.

```
public class PrivateData
{
   public publicInput_;
   private privateInput_;

   public PrivateData(long publicInput, long privateInput)
   {
      publicInput_ = publicInput;
      privateInput_ = privateInput
   }
}
```

But, this class inside the library when debugging can see the private variable that is part of the PrivateData class when providing this class as part of a jar.  I couldn't find what the appropriate way to handle this issue would be.  Perhaps some sort of Opaque class that obscures the actual value of the private data to be seen at the debug window when the user is using it?  This data goes out and back into the library, so I had thought there would be a way to keep a portion of it hidden for ourselves without doing some sort of internal hash mapping on a key value passed out and then re-mapping when it comes back in.

Comment: Why do you need to obscure the value from a debugging session? Private fields will still restrict access in the way the private modifier is intended to. Anyone could always use reflection to change the access modifier of your field at runtime as well.

Comment: If your data is on my device, I can read it. The `private` access modifier is intended to support object oriented design. It is not a security mechanism.

Comment: @MarkW The value itself would provide proprietary data that if discovered by someone could potentially be valuable in re-producing trade secret data; it is a spec design to hide the information that has been assigned.

Comment: @DavidConrad That's not true at all, there are plenty of ways to obscure data, whether that's by not providing any knowledge of certain data pieces existence in native code, encryption or many other manners of concealing data.  However, I would have thought there was a common practice for paired data and a shared object that  could be put to use within library design architectures.  Sounds as though the best option would be not to pass around the pertinent data within the shared object at all then and restructure this a bit.

Comment: Anything that can be done in software, can be undone in software. If your app has the data encrypted, it must contain the keys (and the code) to decrypt it. It must also occasionally decrypt the data, and have the plain data in some variable or register somewhere. If it contains the encrypted data, and the keys to decrypt it, a determined attacker can get it.

Comment: @DavidConrad Not constructive here.  That's just saying that no matter what you do, there is always a way to get to data with enough effort.  Data that should be protected should always be protected.  Don't fall back on such comments such as those.

Comment: You're advocating security through obscurity. Good luck with that.

Comment: @DavidConrad Seconded... to quote NIST "System security should not depend on the secrecy of the implementation or its components."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll start with some potential obscurity approaches discovered if the information is requested to be shared yet obscured.  One approach would be to do some management within the native layer and hold onto an opaque pointer within the class that is being passed around.

```
public class PrivateData
{
   public Object publicInput_;
   private long privateInputPointer_;

   private native static long jniStoreObject(Object privateInput); 

   public PrivateData(Object publicInput, Object privateInput)
   {
      publicInput_ = publicInput;
      privateInput_ = jniStoreObject(privateInput);
   }
}
```

With this approach you should not be accessing the native object frequently or performance hits would be encountered.  Additional mangling of the underlying data can be performed as desired.

Another approach would be to store encrypted byes of a private object and de-encrypt those when the object re-enters the library for the purposes that we would need internally when it comes back through.

```
public class PrivateData
{
    public Object publicInput_;
    private ByteBuffer privateInputBuffer_;

    public PrivateData(Object publicInput, Object privateInput)
    {
       publicInput_ = publicInput;
       privateInputBuffer_ = encrypt(privateInput_);
    }

    Object getPrivateInfo()
    {
       return decrypt(privateInputBuffer_);
    }
}
```

With the second approach there is a delay in the encryption / decryption, but any available data to the user seen through the debug window would then be mangled bytes that would be useless except to the library itself when it needs it.  These were some of the potential approaches that I have seen for handling a situation such as this when a library is requested to have this type of capability.